# How to use lambda function for multiple classification?

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda, classification

Example:

```py
lambda r: 'red' if r == 1 elif 'yellow' r== 2 elif 'green' r==3 elif 'blue' r== 4 else 'black'
```

I want something like this, but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Comment: A lambda function more complex than a single if/else is not worth it. Just create a regular function and replace the lambda with the function object

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Answer (score 1):

```
func = lambda r: {1:'red',2:'yellow',3:'green',4:'blue'}.get(r,'no such color')
print(func(2)) # yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd use a regular `def` function.

If I had to use a `lambda`, based on what you want to do, I'd do this:

```
lambda r: ("red", "yellow", "green", "blue")[r - 1] if 1 <= r <= 4 else "black"
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, perhaps a lambda isn't the best way to solve this problem.

But if you really do want a lambda, here is the correct syntax:

```
lambda r: 'red' if r == 1 else 'yellow' if r == 2 else 'green' if r == 3 else 'blue' if r == 4 else 'black'
```